# How to play video files on Raspberry Pi using push buttons?

Tags: gpio, video, kodi, omxplayer

I have a Raspberry Pi Model B+ and I would like to play video files that are stored on a USB flash drive.

Basically, I have three different push buttons connected to the GPIO pins of the Raspberry Pi and when one button is pressed, then video 1 plays. If button 2 is pressed, then video 2 plays and so on and so forth.

My video files are in **mp4** format.

Can this be done using **omxplayer** or **XBMC**? Or do I have to write a set of codes in Python or C?

Comment: Yes, yes, yes and yes. Hello and welcome. Please note that your question is very broad and therefore hard to answer.

Comment: I'd try to write a python script which waits for button presses and then launches the omxplayer

Answer (score 1):

Use Python.
Use the RPi.GPIO library to detect button presses.
Issue system commands to run omxplayer depending on which button is pressed.